# Unable to get bootstrap-sass running with npm

Tags: jquery, module, npm, gulp, bootstrap-sass

Currently have set up a project with npm using gulp. 
node_modules-map containing bootstrap-sass and jquery-folders.

I build from a src-folder to a dist-folder. The dist-folder gets loaded up in the webbrowser. styles etc.

In my main.scss (src/styles/main.scss) I import the bootstrap.scss:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

all working, except I am not able to get jQuery running (and bootstrap nav menu on mobile also does not seem to be working so I am thing that bootstrap.js is also not loaded in)

bootstrap-sass was installed with: npm install bootstrap --save
jquery was installed with npm install jquery --save

main.js code (src/scripts/main.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( 'ready!' );
});
```

console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:3
```

So I already searched and changed code within the main.js

my main.js file code:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap-sass');

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( 'ready!' );
});
```

but now getting the following error in the browserconsole.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at main.js:2
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue. Were you ever able to find a solution!?

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error, this is what I came up with while using bootstrap-sass and jQuery. Note the capital 'Q' in the code below. :)

```
const $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
```

then, with browserify, you should be good. :D